# Login to website, that require javascript with python

Tags: python, authentication, request

I'm trying to login to this website/browsergame [Travian login](http://ts8.travian.com/?lang=en). I have been searching for some time now, tried different modules, but so far I haven't succeeded...

```
import requests

# Fill in your details here to be posted to the login form.
payload = {
'name': 'username',
'password': 'password'
}

# Use 'with' to ensure the session context is closed after use.
with requests.Session() as s:
p = s.post('http://ts8.travian.com/dorf1.php', data=payload)
# print the html returned or something more intelligent to see if it's a     successful login page.
print(p.text)

# An authorised request.
r = s.get('http://ts8.travian.com/statistiken.php')
print(r.text)
    # etc...
```

When it prints out r.text, the html code looks like it failed.. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What response are you getting? What are you expecting?

Comment: Looking in the returned html, it's the same login screen. Like if you attempt to go to a link that's required account information, I would ask you to login first.

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending all the correct params that they are expecting. They expect more than just the user/pass.

Here's some of my code for params I've used with Delphi

```
  PostData.Add('name='+Username);
  PostData.Add('password='+Password);
  PostData.Add('s1='+'login');
  PostData.Add('w='+'1440:900'); //mod'd for example 
  PostData.Add('login='+'1398184793'); // mod'd for example
```

Comment: side note: if you play still, on which server? :)